# Delete some symbols from Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Friends:

I want to update some nonstandard fill for a address table in sql-server,here is my data:

```
country       state
China         shang(here have Tab key filed)hai
Japan         Tokyo,
England       London(here have Enter key filed)
……
```

The result I want is:

```
country       state
China         shanghai
Japan         Tokyo
England       London
……
```

I don't know how to achieve it. Who can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code removes tab,new line and carriage return..

```
UPDATE <table>
SET state = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(state, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '');

/*
CHAR(9)     - Tab
CHAR(10)    - New Line
CHAR(13)    - Carriage Return
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be other "non-standard" things outside of tab, line feeds and commas, and that the only things that should be in the "state" column are letters and spaces, the following should produce the desired result:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Country
        , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [State]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([State], 1, PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [State]) - 1)
            ELSE [State] END StatePart
        , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [State]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([State], PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [State]) + 1, LEN([State])) ELSE '' END SubState
    FROM tblName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tt.Country
        , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', SubState) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(SubState, 1, PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', SubState) - 1)
            ELSE SubState END
        , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', SubState) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(SubState, PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', SubState) + 1, LEN(SubState)) ELSE '' END
    FROM tblName
    JOIN CTE ON CTE.Country = tblName.Country
    WHERE SubState <> '' 
    --AND PATINDEX('%[a-z ]%', SubState) > 0
    )
UPDATE tblName
SET [State] = STUFF((SELECT StatePart + ''
        FROM CTE
        WHERE Country = T.Country
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,0,'') 
FROM CTE T 
JOIN tblName ON tblName.Country = T.Country
-- SELECT Country, [State] FROM tblName
```

If you can also have spaces as "non-standard" fill in the "state" column, then you'd need to remove each of the spaces in the square brackets for the `PATINDEX` here. The issue being that this would also remove any legitimate spaces.